# clear all pending $http requests and reload page in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-routing

i tried $route.reload(); location.reload(true); $window.location.reload(true);but pending requests are not cancelling/aborting, page is reloading, how to hard reload page means closing all $http requests which are pending and reloading page.

Comment: Have a look at abort() method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/446626/2674883

Comment: yeah, like abort i need one global function for $http, so that i can call anywhere?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928057/how-do-to-cancel-an-http-request-in-angularjs

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick for you. You'll need to call the `abortAllPendingRequests` method when you want to cancel your requests.

Please keep in mind that this solution does require the use of underscore. I haven't tried it with lodash.

```
(function ()
{
  angular.module('myApp')
    .run(function ($http, $q)
    {
      $http.currentlyPendingRequests = [];

      $http.accessPendingRequests = function (pending)
      {
        if (!arguments.length) return this.currentlyPendingRequests;
        this.currentlyPendingRequests = pending;
      };

      $http.removeRequest = function (requestUrl)
      {
        this.currentlyPendingRequests = _.filter(this.currentlyPendingRequests, function (request)
        {
          return request.url !== requestUrl;
        }, this)
      };

      $http.abortAllPendingRequests = function ()
      {
        _.each(this.currentlyPendingRequests, function (request)
        {
          request.aborter.resolve();
        });

        this.currentlyPendingRequests = [];
      };

      var originalGet = $http.get;

      $http.get = function ()
      {
        // Ignore template requests
        if (arguments[0].indexOf('.html') != -1)
        {
          return originalGet.apply(this, arguments)
        };

        var aborter =  $q.defer();
        var url     = arguments[0];

        this.currentlyPendingRequests.push({url : url, aborter : aborter});
        console.log('pushing url : ' + url);

        // Include the abortion promise in the new arguments
        var newArgs        = [arguments[0], _.extend({}, arguments[1], {timeout : aborter.promise})];
        var requestPromise = originalGet.apply(this, newArgs);

        // Finally is a reserved word and is not es3 compatible, and therefore non compliant for ie8. Thus the hash
        // syntax must be used.
        requestPromise['finally'](function()
        {
          this.removeRequest(url);
        });

        return requestPromise;

      }
    });
})();
```