# Cancelling a request with a $http interceptor?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to use a `$http` interceptor to cancel a request before it even happens.

> There is a button that triggers a request but if the user double-clicks it I do not want the same request to get triggered twice.

Now, I realize that there's several ways to solve this, and we do already have a working solution where we wrap `$http` in a service that keeps track of requests that are currently pending and simply ignores new requests with the same method, url and data.

Basically this is the behaviour I am trying to do with an interceptor:

```
factory('httpService', ['$http', function($http) {

    var pendingCalls = {};

    var createKey = function(url, data, method) {
        return method + url + JSON.stringify(data);
    };

    var send = function(url, data, method) {
        var key = createKey(url, data, method);
        if (pendingCalls[key]) {
            return pendingCalls[key];
        }
        var promise = $http({
            method: method,
            url: url,
            data: data
        });
        pendingCalls[key] = promise;
        promise.finally(function() {
            delete pendingCalls[key];
        });
        return promise;
    };

    return {
        post: function(url, data) {
            return send(url, data, 'POST');
        }
    }

}])
```

When I look at the API for `$http` interceptors it does not seem to be a way to achieve this. I have access to the `config` object but that's about it.

Am I attempting to step outside the boundaries of what interceptors can be used for here or is there a way to do it?

Comment: I think that was answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/17328336/2938008

Comment: Nope. That approach would require me to go around and add a timeout-promise in every single class that uses $http which is exactly what I am trying to avoid having to do. It would also cancel the request instead of preventing it from happening.

Comment: Are you looking for a viewmodel way ($http.interceptor) of doing this as opposed to using the view?  Like disabling the button when it is clicked, and re-enable when you receive your success callback?

Comment: @user1518802 Not really, I was hoping to find a way to do this with interceptors to stop having to make everyone in the team remember to inject a custom service instead of using $http directly. I feel that disabling buttons is more of a UX concern while this is more of a way to mitigate problems with duplicate requests to the backend. We do replace buttons with spinners when they're clicked but that is done with a directive. I actually don't think this question as it stands has a solution.

Comment: https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth This is something we use to intercept all http calls and validate them with auth. Maybe you can find some way of suiting it to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

according to [$http documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), you can return your own config from request interceptor.

try something like this:

```
config(function($httpProvider) {
    var cache = {};

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
        return {
            response : function(config) {
                var key = createKey(config);
                var cached = cache[key];
                return cached ? cached : cached[key];    
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm not really looking for a cache, two GET requests at two different points in time might return different results. What I was hoping to achieve was to cancel a request to any given resource if there was already one in place. I played around with your approach in plnkr but all I really achieved was to cache a response while still triggering duplicate requests. If you look carefully at the service I posted it actually stops a second request from happening but only while a duplicate request has not returned. It also feeds both callers the same promise. It's not a caching mechanism.

Comment: @ivarni, yes, you can't handle promises with interceptors. for this case your Model pattern approach seems valid. i'd change 'promise.then' to 'promise.finally' though.

Comment: That's a VERY good point :) Luckily we eject users after any failed HTTP call but if we didn't that could have caused some nasty issues.

Comment: @ilj can you elaborate why this is the case?

Comment: @hugoderhungrige `promise.then` (with no error-callback) only gets executed on a succesful request, while `promise.finally`gets executed on all requests. In this case the pending request should be purged also if it fails. Be a bit careful though, older versions of IE does not approve of the use of `finally` in that context as it's a reserved word. I can't recall if it's a problem with IE8 or IE9 though.

Comment: @ivarni, can't you use promise['finally'] syntax for it?

Comment: @hugoderhungrige, not sure what exactly you were asking for. did ivarni's answer help?

Answer (score 1):

Very old question, but I'll give a shot to handle this situation.

If I understood correctly, you are trying to:

1 - Start a request and register something to refer back to it;

2 - If another request takes place, to the same endpoint, you want to retrieve that first reference and drop the request in it.

This might be handled by a request timeout in the `$http` config object. On the interceptor, you can verify it there's one registered on the current request, if not, you can setup one, keep a reference to it and handle if afterwards:

```
function DropoutInterceptor($injector) {
    var $q = $q || $injector.get('$q');
    var dropouts = {};

    return {
        'request': function(config) {
            // I'm using the request's URL here to make
            // this reference, but this can be bad for
            // some situations.
            if (dropouts.hasOwnProperty(config.url)) {
                // Drop the request
                dropouts[config.url].resolve();
            }

            dropouts[config.url] = $q.defer();

            // If the request already have one timeout
            // defined, keep it, othwerwise, set up ours.
            config.timeout = config.timeout || dropouts[config.url];

            return config;
        },
        'requestError': function(reason) {
            delete dropouts[reason.config.url];

            return $q.reject(reason);
        },
        'response': function(response) {
            delete dropouts[response.config.url];

            return response;
        },
        'responseError': function(reason) {
            delete dropouts[reason.config.url];

            return $q.reject(reason);
        }
    };
}
```