# JavaScript service: how to provide a () method, like an object constructor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to create a service that will create [an interface to AngularJS's `$http` based on this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23244389/angularjs-abort-all-pending-http-requests-on-route-change)  I would like to use dependency injection to inject the service without re-writing individual function calls and keeping the code clean.  To do this I am providing a common service that creates a variable to the $http object like this:

```
commonService = function(...) {
return {
    ...
    $http: $http
}
```

Then I use `common.$http` everywhere in the code. To change $http from AngularJS $http to my httpService, I need to only change it in one place.  httpService looks like this:

```
function httpService($http, $q, pendingRequests, $interval) {
var get = function(url) {
    ...
    return requestPromise;
};

var service = {
    get:get
};

return service;
```

}

This works for calls to `$http.get()` but what about calls to `$http({method:'get', url:'...'});` ?

Is it possible to provide the () method, which is really httpService()()?  Otherwise it would call the AngularJs method httpService().

Comment: I think you are looking for decorators https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#decorator

Comment: `()` isn't a method. It's just invoking a function that was returned. If that's what you want, then just return a function that performs whatever action you need.

Comment: @major-mann how does that work?  like `$provide.decorator((), $http);`?

Comment: Here is a blog entry which should get you going http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/10/07/enhance-angularjs-logging-using-decorators/ :)

Comment: Basically $provide.decorator( '$http', [ "$delegate", function( $delegate ) {} ... inside, $delegate is the original $http.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just return a function instead of an object. You can add the properties to your function

```
function httpService($http, $q, pendingRequests, $interval) {
   var get = function(url) {
      ...
      return requestPromise;
   };

  // Instead of returning an object, return a function
  var service = function() {
    // do whatever you want here
  };

  service.get = get;

  // Add more properties to service as needed

  return service;
}
```