# Preventing subsequent $http calls in angularjs when one fails

Tags: angularjs, http, request-cancelling

In my project, we are using angularjs and RESTful APIs. 
Let's say I am trying to load a page, where we may be making calls to 6 rest apis. Say the first one fails- meaning I get a 200 but there is actually an exception that has occurred in the Java layer. How do I cancel all the future calls or rather stop those remaining 5 calls from being made? I am aware of the concept of interceptors and have referred to the following post

[AngularJS abort all pending $http requests on route change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23244389/angularjs-abort-all-pending-http-requests-on-route-change)

I am intercepting the response for each call to check if it has any error message that we are sending from the Java layer and then cancelling calls that have been registered in the array. But in case of the first call, that is the only one that will be present in the array. I am stuck with how to prevent further calls from happening.

Comment: You want to look into promise chaining: http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/12/27/javascript-promise-chains-2/

Comment: Show us the code. It's unclear if these calls are made in parallel or one after the other. BTW, Why does the server return 200 if an exception has occurred. That's what I would fix. Return an error code to signal an error: that's what they're for.