# Abort HTTP request when redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-http

I got this page which uses Angular and when the page is loaded, it requests some data from a HTTP get call. My problem is that if the user navigates to a other page while the HTTP get call is going on, the system gives a error and then gives me the HTTP error callback showing the alert with "Error".

```
$http.get('/api/something/).success(function (data, status, headers, config) { 
        alert(data);        
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        alert('Error');
    });
```

What I want instead is to just abort the http call and then move the user to the other page without the error function being called.

So far I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928057/how-to-cancel-an-http-request-in-angularjs).

But I can't see how I can use it to fix my problem.

Comment: We used the answer found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23244389/angularjs-abort-all-pending-http-requests-on-route-change

Comment: You are aware of the fact that you've got a syntax error, you never close the '/api/something/

Comment: @Alagaros No but it's just a exsample.