# Abort service calls, while switching routes in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Problem Statement:
i am using 3 tabs. tab-a , tab-b and tab-c.
each tab will have 5-6 service calls to web api on document load.  my problem is, when i click on tab-a..calls from tab-a starts quickly on change of route. but if i click on tab-b sametime, my previous calls will be in process and new more 6 calls will be added from tab-b. i want to abort previous calls from  tab-a on switching route. becuase it effects the perofrmance of my Angular SPA.

I am using angular js routing.

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when('/daily',
{
    title: 'Daily - Stats',
    templateUrl: '/SPA/Daily.html'
})
.when('/weekly',
{
    title: 'Weekly - Stats',
    templateUrl: '/SPA/Weekly.html'
})
```

i have one service to get and post data from web apis.

Comment: maybe can help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928057/how-to-cancel-an-http-request-in-angularjs

Comment: It is fine, but not working in my scenario. kindly suggest me some piece of code, according to above flow.
thanks for your kind response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Resolve in $routeprovider ( I haven't tested code)
Like:

```
.when('/daily',
{
title: 'Daily - Stats',
templateUrl: '/SPA/Daily.html',
resolve: {
   foo: function($http){
      $http.pendingRequests.forEach(function (pendingReq) {
      //here cancel pendingReq like pendingReq.resolve()
   }
}
```

or You can use RoutechangeStart.

You can find more also in this post:
[AngularJS abort all pending $http requests on route change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23244389/angularjs-abort-all-pending-http-requests-on-route-change)

Comment: you welcome, remember to accept answer, for other people that have same problem