# Cancel http requests when changing route - Angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to cancel http requests in my angularjs project but I dont know how to do it. I am not that good with AngularJS so I am having trouble where and what I should do. Tried implementing something like [this](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/04/24/canceling-http-requests-in-angularjs.aspx) but failed.

What I want is to cancel http requests on requests in one service only. This is example of one request I have there:

```
    app.factory('reportService', function ($http, $state, toastService, $q) {
        var factory = {};

        factory.clicks = function (filter) {
            return $http({
                url: config.baseAddress + 'Report/Clicks',
                method: 'POST',
                data: filter
            }).then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            },
            function (response) {
                toastService.error(response, 'reportService.clicks');
                return $q.reject(response);
            });
        };
});
```

Should I do something here, or maybe in app.js?

Comment: can `.then` be resolved in the controller instead?

Comment: Have you tried using "resolve" object in route config?

Comment: @hamzox what should I do with resolve object? I have it in my route config but it only returns some parameters atm

Comment: @AlekseySolovey this is some dinasour project where I avoid changing anything I dont absolutely have to, if it is the only way to do it then it could be resolved in the controller, yeah

Comment: i think this anwser could help https://stackoverflow.com/a/31273992/8303694