# Cancel / Abort all pending requests in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

On route change, I need to abort ALL pending requests from previous route so that I don't run into problems of responses from previous route messing up data on my current route (it happens sometimes when responses from previous route take long time to finish).

I have thought about using [http interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for this:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
    return {
     'request': function(config) {

      },

      'response': function(response) {

      }
    };
  });
```

In the request function, I could modify the `config.timeout` with a promise as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928057/how-to-cancel-an-http-request-in-angularjs) and store all the deferred objects in a global cache so that I could cancel all of them.

The problem with this approach is that it may **override** `config.timeout` set in other places in the code.

I think another solution could be to cancel all ajax requests at `XMLHttpRequest` level, but I don't know how to do it.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: If the `config.timeout` is already set in other place, you could still  combine it with the promise for this purpose together.

Comment: Even if there was a built in way to cancel all pending `XMLHttpRequest`s wouldn't it cause trouble by i.e. not loading html templates. Furthermore it's very common to have an fire&forget action which you don't want to cancel even though you've moved to another screen...

Comment: @runTarm: how to do it? Anyway, I think that `timeout` is another concept separated from `abort`. It's a trick when we take advantage of `timeout` to abort a request (we should avoid tricks when coding).

Comment: @miensol: it would not cause trouble not loading html because I've moved to another route. I'm working on an existing code base, I cannot just fire&forget, this is causing problems in the app.

Comment: I don't think the `timeout` is a trick or a dirty hack. It is the only API that `$http` service exposed for aborting ajax request, at least as of now.

Comment: @runTarm: I think I agree with the second answer from the link in the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928057/how-to-cancel-an-http-request-in-angularjs

Answer (score 7):

As you say, `timeout` is the only API we have of use right now to cancel a running $http request. I think you're right on the money with an interceptor coupled with a cancel promise.

What you could do is attach the full deferred object on the `$http` request, and cancel all [pendingRequests](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#pendingRequests) in your route change handler.

Something like this could (perhaps*) work?

```
angular.module('module').config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q) {
    return {
      request: function (config) {
        if (!config.timeout) {
          config.cancel  = $q.defer();
          config.timeout = config.cancel.promise;            
        }

        return config;
      }
    }
  });
});

angular.module('module').run(function ($rootScope, $http) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function () {
    $http.pendingRequests.forEach(function (pendingReq) {
      if (pendingReq.cancel) {
        pendingReq.cancel.resolve('Cancel!');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

*: I say perhaps, because I had success with this approach, but it's seldom you find a silver bullet to something like this.

---

**edit**

If you need to bypass the error handler of the cancelled promise, hook into `responseError` property and do manual labour there.

```
angular.module('module').config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q) {
    return {
      responseError: function (response) {
        if (response.config.timeout.$$state.value === 'Cancel!') {
          // debugger; 
          return $q.when('bypassed');
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I'm starting to think that there is no generic/'cool' solution to reach the end result you desire. Treading some odd ground here : )

---

**edit2:**

Testing the above myself now. Returning `$q.when('something')` in the `responseError` will effectively bypass the error callback of the cancelled `$http` request. Let me know if it works out for you.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but as i said: `The problem with this approach is that it may override config.timeout set in other places in the code.`

Comment: Hence the `if (!config.timeout)` condition.

Comment: another problem I forgot to mention. When we cancel using timeout promise, the error callback is called which is not desirable. How can we solve this? I asked the question because I thought there may be other solutions without using timeout promise.

Comment: edited my answer to touch on where you could possibly bypass the error/success handler of the cancelled promise.

Comment: Thanks for the solution sir !!, works well, didn't find any problems / bugs so far :P, any other solutions ?

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But is the following error intentionally made to break the callback flow?
`Cannot create property 'resource' on string 'bypassed'`