# Aborting An AJAX Request In AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

```
if (xhr != null) { // xhr is AJAX call request object.
    console.log("abort");
    canceler.resolve();
}

xhr = $http({ method: 'POST', url:("/Home/GetLibrary"), timeout: canceler.promise })
    .success(){
        alert("success");
    })
    .error() {
        alert("error");
    });
```

Here I check the xhr object. If xhr object is not null then I abort the call. But it aborts the current call, not the previous Ajax call.
I try to call the same function again, then all subsequent AJAX call are aborted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 var canceller = $q.defer();
     
    $http.get("yourUrl", { data:data })
         .then(function(response){
            $scope.movie = response.data;
        });
     
    $scope.cancel = function(){
        canceller.resolve("user cancelled");  
    };
```

$scope.cancel();

Comment: I tried this. but $scope.cancel function is not called any cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through promises. Have a look at [Aborting AJAX Requests Using $http And AngularJS](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2616-aborting-ajax-requests-using-http-and-angularjs.htm), the guy explained the topic very well.

Also check the following question :

[How to cancel an $http request in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928057/how-to-cancel-an-http-request-in-angularjs)