# Abort pending ajax request in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, abort

How can I abort my pending `ajax` requests in `AngularJS`? I am using a `Service` for making an ajax call and want to abort all pending requests if a new one is made on the same route.

Here is my service:

```
myService.service('angService', function($http){

  this.getfromRemote=function(url){
    return $http.get(location+'/dev/apiv-1-0-2/'+url);
  }
});
```

Here I am calling the service. Before running next, I want to abort the pending ajax requests.

```
angService.getfromRemote('paymentStatement/'+$scope.username)
                            .success(function(response){

})
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to cancel an $http request in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928057/how-to-cancel-an-http-request-in-angularjs)

Comment: its not working for me

Answer (score 0):

To abort a pending `$http` request, you can pass a promise to the timeout property of the `$http` request, and call `resolve` to abort the request.

```
myService.service('angService',function($http, $q){
    var pending = false;
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    this.getfromRemote=function(url){
        if (pending) {
           deferred.resolve();
           deferred = $q.defer();
        }
        pending = true;
        return $http({ 
           method: 'GET', 
           url: location+'/dev/apiv-1-0-2/'+url,
           timeout = deferred.promise;
        }).then(function(result) {
           pending = false;
           deferred = $q.defer();
           return result;
        }, function(result) {
           pending = false;
           deferred = $q.defer();
           return result;
        });


    }

});
```