# how to cancel http request in angular js on button click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am calling web service in angular js . I am able to get data using $http.But I create a situation when I want to cancel my request after few seconds .I call service after 2 second .then press cancel request button .on click of that button I need to cancel my request which is try to get data from server .can we do in angular js to cancel request

here is my code

```
.factory('acservice', ['$http','$q', function($http,$q) {
    var canceler = $q.defer();

    return {
        callDisputeServiceLocal: function(successcallback, errorcallback) {
            return $http.get('https:/******.com/s/9wkl32e23vdvs6h/default.json?dl=0',{timeout: canceler.promise}).success(successcallback).error(errorcallback);



        },
        cancelRequest:function(){
         canceler.resolve();  
        }

    }
```

**Edit** already use this but not working

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928057/how-to-cancel-an-http-request-in-angularjs

Comment: already try it is not working ..!!

Comment: I will give you updated plubker

Comment: hi shruti, are you still getting the same error

Comment: @Vineet I tried please check update plunker ..When I click it is not cancel my request ..is this a way ?

Comment: You've given too many plunkers, which one is showing your error  ?

Comment: all are same please check the edit plunker or comment plunker

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I will post it as an answer as it is slightly different.

```
var canceler = $q.defer();
$http.get('/myUrl' { timeout: canceler.promise })
    .success(function (response) {
        console.log(response)
    })
    .error(function () {
        console.log('error')
    });
canceler.resolve("user cancelled");
```

You get that in networking console of Chrome:

[image: link]