# Why can't I cancel this Angular HTTP request?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I'm using the code found from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928057/how-to-cancel-an-http-request-in-angularjs) SO post to cancel my HTTP requests mid-request if they time out:

```
var canceller = $q.defer();

$timeout(function() {
  canceller.resolve();
  alert("HTTP request failed.");
}, 5000);

$http({
  url: endpoint + "/encode",
  timeout: canceller.promise,
  data: {
    post: posts.post[id]
  }
}).success(successFunction);
```

However, I keep getting `ReferenceError: timeout is not defined` in my console.  What could I possibly be doing wrong here?

Comment: Is your actual code missing the `$`? What does the stack trace say, which line does throw the exception?

Comment: No, that's not what it says to do in the documentation.

Comment: Protip: `$timeout()` itself returns a promise. Better avoid the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572).

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the tip.  But this isn't interfering with my code now, correct?

Comment: I don't think so. Regardless, the code you've shown us does not use a variable `timeout`, so that's not where the error comes from.

Comment: what's your http method? is it post or get method?

Comment: What is the version of angularjs you are using? And in your case you can directly give timeout:5000 instead of promise object.

Comment: I am using get, and I'm on angular 1.3

Answer (score 1):

So without a plunker it's difficult to replicate but I successfully cancelled a http request using your code for inspiration. [Plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/EaM855?p=preview)

**Controller.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $q, $http, $timeout) {

  $scope.msg = 'Not done it';

  var canceller = $q.defer();

  $scope.doThis = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
      canceller.resolve();
      $scope.msg = "I cancelled it";
    }, 1);

    $scope.msg = "I did it";
    var url = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22nome%2C%20ak%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys';
    var request = $http.get( url, {timeout: canceller.promise});
    request.success(function(results) {
      $scope.msg = "I loaded some data";
      $scope.data = results;
    });
  }
});
```

**view.html**

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <p>{{msg}}</p>
    <a href="" ng-click="doThis()">Do This</a>
    <p>
      {{data}}
    </p>
  </body>
```

Comment: That's really strange.  Why do you think that my code won't work?