# Order of promises in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise, cancellation

**Question:**

Is there an "easy" way to cancel (`$q`-/`$http`-)promises in AngularJS or determine the order in which promises were resolved?

**Example**

I have a long running calculation and i request the result via `$http`. Some actions or events require me to restart the calculation (and thus sending a new `$http` request) before the initial promise is resolved. Thus i imagine i can't use a simple implementation like

```
$http.post().then(function(){
    //apply data to view
})
```

because I can't ensure that the responses come back in the order in which i did send the requests - after all i want to show the result of the latest calculation when all promises were resolved properly.

However I would like to **avoid** waiting for the first response until i send a new request like this:

```
const timeExpensiveCalculation = function(){
    return $http.post().then(function(response){
        if (isNewCalculationChained) {return timeExpensiveCalculation();}            
        else {return response.data;}
    })
}
```

**Thoughts:**

When using `$http` i can access the config-object on the response to use some timestamps or other identifiers to manually order the incoming responses. However i was hoping I could just tell angular somehow to cancel an outdated promise and thus not run the .then() function when it gets resolved.

This does not work without manual implementation for `$q`-promises instead of `$http` though.

Maybe just rejecting the promise right away is the way to go? But in both cases it might take forever until finally a promise is resolved before the next request is generated (which leads to an empty view in the meantime).

Is there some angular API-Function that i am missing or are there robust design patterns or "tricks" with promise chaining or $q.all to handle multiple promises that return the "same" data?

Comment: Not sure what your using for an API but in my .Net apis I've used SignalR to handle scenarios like this.

Comment: Great question, looking forward to answers.  But wouldn't it be a lot easier to handle the logic within the .then instead of trying to avoid the promise from being resolved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Promise - is it possible to force cancel a promise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233302/promise-is-it-possible-to-force-cancel-a-promise)

Comment: Here is a duplicate of being able to cancel an $http request http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928057/how-to-cancel-an-http-request-in-angularjs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do it by generating a `requestId`, and in the promise's `then()` function I check if the response is coming from the most recent `requestId`.

While this approach does not actually cancel the previous promises, it does provide a quick and easy way to ensure that you are handling the most recent request's response.

Something like:

```
var activeRequest;
function doRequest(params){
    // requestId is the id for the request being made in this function call
    var requestId = angular.toJson(params); // I usually md5 hash this

    // activeRequest will always be the last requestId sent out
    activeRequest = requestId;

    $http.get('/api/something', {data: params})
        .then(function(res){
            if(activeRequest == requestId){
                // this is the response for last request

                // activeRequest is now handled, so clear it out
                activeRequest = undefined;
            }
            else {
                // response from previous request (typically gets ignored)
            }
        });
}
```

**Edit:**
On a side-note, I wanted to add that this concept of tracking `requestId's` can also be applied to preventing duplicate requests.  For example, in my `Data` service's `load(module, id)` method, I do a little process like this:

1. generate the `requestId` based on the URL + parameters.
2. check in requests hash-table for the `requestId`

   - if `requestId` is not found: generate new request and store promise in hash-table
   - if `requestId` is found: simply return the promise from the hash-table
3. When the request finishes, remove the `requestId`'s entry from the hash-table.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will accept this answer since it actually refers to angularJS which is what i asked for. The answer of Redu contains a working example for this technique (without using Angular)

Answer (score 4):

Cancelling a promise is just making it not invoke the `onFulfilled` and `onRejected` functions at the `then` stage. So as @user2263572 mentioned it's always best to let go the promise not cancelled (ES6 native promises can not be cancelled anyways) and handle this condition within it's `then` stage (like disregarding the task if a global variable is set to 2 as shown in the following snippet) and i am sure you can find tons of other ways to do it. One example could be;

Sorry that i use `v` (looks like check character) for `resolve` and `x` (obvious) for `reject` functions.

```js
var    prom1 = new Promise((v,x) => setTimeout(v.bind(null,"You shall not read this"),2000)),
       prom2,
validPromise = 1;
prom1.then(val => validPromise === 1 && console.log(val));
// oh what have i done..!?! Now i have to fire a new promise
prom2 = new Promise((v,x) => setTimeout(v.bind(null,"This is what you will see"),3000));
validPromise = 2;
prom2.then(val => validPromise === 2 && console.log(val));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still trying to figure out a good way to unit test this, but you could try out this kind of strategy:

```
var canceller = $q.defer();
service.sendCalculationRequest = function () {
    canceller.resolve();
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/do-calculation',
        timeout: canceller.promise
    });
};
```

Comment: I found this in another thread after i posted this question. This still only works for `$http` calls though.

Comment: Ah I see, so you are looking for something with `$resource`.

Answer (score 0):

In ECMA6 promises, [there is a `Promise.race(promiseArray)` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race).  This takes an array of promises as its argument, and returns a single promise.  The first promise to resolve in the array will hand off its resolved value to the `.then` of the returned promise, while the other array promises that came in second, etc., will not be waited upon.

Example:

```
var httpCall1 = $http.get('/api/something', {data: params})
    .then(function(val) { 
        return { 
            id: "httpCall1"
            val: val
        }
    })
var httpCall2 = $http.get('/api/something-else', {data: params})
    .then(function(val) { 
        return { 
            id: "httpCall2"
            val: val
        }
    })
// Might want to make a reusable function out of the above two, if you use this in Production
Promise.race([httpCall1, httpCall2])
    .then(function(winningPromise) {
        console.log('And the winner is ' + winningPromise.id);
        doSomethingWith(winningPromise.val);
    });
```

You could either use this with a Promise polyfil, or [look into the q.race that someone's developed for Angular](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/b9a56d588f8b597b1dff30d8e184b7c37d94cdcf) (though I haven't tested it).

Comment: this might have some other very useful applications but with this method i get "random" data (depending on the times the promises need to resolve) instead of the most up-to-date. So it does not answer the question unless i am missing something.