# How do I simulate a client aborting request?

Tags: java, apache, http, tomcat

I'm tasked with solving a reported bug, where the logs show a

```
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:205)
```

[There are several questions here about the ClientAbortException](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=clientabortexception%20is%3Aquestion), and my understanding from reading them, and [also the Tomcat javadoc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/ClientAbortException.html),  is that the exception is thrown by Tomcat when the client aborts the HTTP request.

I'm having trouble reproducing the error. How can I simulate a client abort?

**What I've tried**

- Adding a `Thread.sleep(10000)` in the request handler, and then closing the browser while the request is running - but that doesn't do it.
- Cancelling the HTTP request from the client side using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928057/how-to-cancel-an-http-request-in-angularjs) with angular.

Comment: A `ClientAbortException` can be caused by multiple things. Simulating a client abort will allow you to solve the client abort that you've caused, not every subsequent client abort. For instance this exception can be thrown by a client canceling a download. How will simulating that help you solve a timeout related client abort exception?

Comment: @JonnyHenly - It's the first step in debugging the application. If I understand what kind of things cause a `ClientAbortException`, then I know what to look for.

Comment: Found a [Tomcat forum post](http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/Question-on-ClientAbortException-td2158595.html) that states -- *The APR `flushBuffer()` method got a negative response from the native `Socket.sendbb()` method in the APR library.  The usual cause is client disconnect, but other less common network errors could trigger it.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, with a bit of experimenting - I've found a way to do it.

What it looks like - is that if an http request is cancelled/timed out by the client *while the server is writing/flushing the output* then the error will be thrown. (**NB.** It appears as if the size of the response also matters - see my note at the end).

There are three things that can happen:

---

**Condition 1:** Server writes and flushes output before client timeouts.

Response is sent back to client.

**Condition 2:** Client times out before server writes and flushes output.

Client does not receive response, no server error.

**Condition 3:** Client times out while server is writing output.

Client does not receive response. Server throws `ClientAbortException` (`java.io.IOException`).

---

To simulate these three conditions, we play with three variables:

1. The time client takes to timeout
2. Time server burns getting its result.
3. The size of the server response.

Here is the test code to simulate it:

**Server side** (This is a Spring MVC controller).

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/debugGet" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<String> debugGet(@RequestParam int timeout, int numObjects) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(timeout);

    List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i =0; i< numObjects; i++){
        l.add(new String());
    }


    return l;

}
```

**Client side** (Angular)

```
this.debugGet = function(server, client, numObjects){       

    var httpProm = $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "debugGet",
        timeout: client,
        params : {
            timeout: server,
            numObjects: numObjects}
    });             

    httpProm.then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }, function(data){
        console.log("error");
        console.log(data);
    });     
};
```

Using this I can simulate the three conditions with the following params:

```
              Client Timeout     Server Burn Time      Num Strings
Condition 1:   1000                900                   10000
Condition 2:   1000                2000                  100 
Condition 3:   1000                950                   10000
```

**NB** It appears as if the size of response also matters.

For example:

```
              Client Timeout     Server Burn Time      Num Strings
Condition 2:  1000               2000                  100 
Condition 3:  1000               2000                  10000
```

Here for the 10000 Strings, we get the `java.io.IOException` even though the flush occurs well after the client has timed out, whereas it doesn't for the 100 Strings.