# Cancelling old requests in ng-change with debounce

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have a requirement to fetch data through a web service for the search parameter which I type in a textbox. Currently it is working fine with `debounce` in `ng-model-options` and it fires a request after the time I specify.

I couldn't find that does angular cancel the previous incomplete request automatically once a new one is fired.

If not, how should I handle this as each key press will fire a request after the time period I specified.

The HTML is

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="inpTeachers" ng-model="inpTeachers" id="inpTeachers" autocomplete="off" required ng-change="GetTeachers(frmAddSubjectMain)" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: {'default': 500, 'blur': 0} }" placeholder="Ex. Nancy Chang" />
```

And the method `GetTeachers` is just a simple method changing some scope variables after a http request.

Should I be cancelling the old http request if another `ng-change` is fired.

Comment: Posting code, as usual, would help. But since I doubt angular is sending any request, I don't see how it could cancel it. Post the code. You could also just... test it.

Comment: I did not post any code as the existing one is working fine for me. I'll do it now

Comment: @JBNizet now you might get some hint

Comment: Angular has absolutely no idea of what the GetTeachers() method does. It's your own code in that method that sends an HTTP request, and angular can't cancel it.

Comment: So what should be the approach to cancel any existing `$http` requests that are in progress by this `ng-change`?? @JBNizet

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928057/how-to-cancel-an-http-request-in-angularjs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

If you might want to close a fired request, you can use the `timeout` property of the `http's config object`, giving it a `number` (milliseconds)  or a `Promise`.

```
function GetTeachers(frmAddSubjectMain){
  var canceler = $q.defer();
  yourService.retrieveTeachers(canceler).then(function() {
      /* here is your result */
  });
}
```

And in your service, you might need something like:

```
$http.get('/teachers', {timeout: canceler.promise});
```

Whenever you would like to cancel the ongoing request (if it isn't finished yet), just call:

```
canceler.resolve();
```