# How to cancel a $http call from controller in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, http, angular-promise

I am quite new to Angular and i am trying to figure out how to cancel an ajax call from button click, I have written following code please let me know how to add it further.
Thanks in advance...!!!

HTML

```
<a ng-click="cancelCall()" id="pods-cancel-search-button" title="Cancel" class="form-button primary" ><i class="fa fa-search fa-fw"></i>Cancel Search</a>
```

Service

```
paymentSearchApp.service('paymentSearchResponse',['$http', '$log', function($http, $log){
//var response = [];
return {
    findResponse: (function(data){
        return $http({
            url:'data/result.json',
            data:data,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            contentType: 'application/json; characterset=utf-8',
            method: 'POST'
        }).then(function(resp){
            var response = resp;
            return response.data;
        },function(resp){
            $log.error("ERROR occured");
        });
    })
};
 return paymentSearchResponse;


}]);
```

Controller

```
paymentSearchApp.controller('paymentSearchCtrl', function (paymentSearchService,paymentSearchResponse, $scope) {

paymentSearchResponse.findResponse(requestPayLoadPacked).then(
                        function(response){
                            //operation on response
                        },function(){
                            alert("error in getting response from payment search service");
                        }
                        $scope.cancel = function(){
                        alert("cancel ajax call");

                        }
                    );

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [How to cancel an $http request in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928057/how-to-cancel-an-http-request-in-angularjs#answer-17328336).

add additional parameter in your service:

```
paymentSearchApp.service('paymentSearchResponse',['$http', '$log', function($http, $log){
  //var response = [];
  return {
    findResponse: (function(data, timeoutCanceler){
      return $http({
        url: 'data/result.json',
        data: data,
        timeout: timeoutCanceler.promise,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        contentType: 'application/json; characterset=utf-8',
        method: 'POST'
      }).then(function(resp){
        var response = resp;
        return response.data;
      },function(resp){
        $log.error("ERROR occured");
      });
    })
  };
  return paymentSearchResponse;
}]);
```

controller:

```
paymentSearchApp.controller('paymentSearchCtrl', function (paymentSearchService, paymentSearchResponse, $scope, $q) {

  var timeoutCanceler = $q.defer();
  paymentSearchResponse.findResponse(requestPayLoadPacked, timeoutCanceler).then(
     function(response){
       //operation on response
     },function(){
       alert("error in getting response from payment search service");
     };

  $scope.cancelCall = function(){
    timeoutCanceler.resolve();
    alert("cancel ajax call");
  }
);

});
```

I did not check this with live code, but it should give a guide lines

Answer (score 1):

You should use [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q), like:

```
var canceller = $q.defer();

paymentSearchResponse.findResponse(requestPayLoadPacked).then(
                        function(response){
                            //operation on response
                             canceller.resolve(response);
                             return canceller.promise;
                        },function(){
                            alert("error in getting response from payment search service");
                        }
                        $scope.cancel = function(){
                        alert("cancel ajax call");
                        canceller.resolve();
                        }
                    );
```

Read this [manuel](http://www.frontcoded.com/angular-cancel-$http-request.html) First.