# AngularJS - Cancelling a HTTP Request From a Service That Returns a Promise

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I have a service method that looks like:

```
this.myServiceFunction = function(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'domain/myendpoint'
    })
        .success(function(data){
            deferred.resolve(data);
        })
        .error(function(data){
            deferred.reject(data);
        });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

I use this method in my controller in the following fashion:

```
$scope.myControllerFunction = function(){
    myService.myServiceFunction().then(function(){
        // Do things when promise resolves
    });
};
```

I would like to cancel the HTTP call above in another function on command.  I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17328336/1423787) which allows you to cancel a HTTP request by calling the `resolve()` method on the object returned from `$q.defer()`.  But in my codebase, this object is never made available in my controller.

`myService.myServiceFunction()` in the example above returns a `promise` object returned from `$q.defer()`.  How do I cancel my HTTP request within the confines of what I have?

Comment: See [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928057/how-to-cancel-an-http-request-in-angularjs) on this very topic.

Comment: @MarkS. Did you read the question?

Comment: Why don't you use **RxJs**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cancel an $http request in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928057/how-to-cancel-an-http-request-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following answers the question, without the overhead in your original code.

```
this.myServiceFunction = function(){
  this.canceler = $q.defer();
  return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'domain/myendpoint',
    timeout: this.canceler.promise   
  });
};

this.cancelServiceFunction = function() {
  return this.canceler.resolve();
};
```

If however, you are required to use that pattern for some reason, you can use the following:

```
this.myServiceFunction = function(){
  this.canceler = $q.defer();
  this.deferred = $q.defer();

  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'domain/myendpoint',
    timeout: this.canceler.promise   
  })
  .success(function(data){
    deferred.resolve(data);
  })
  .error(function(data){
    deferred.reject(data);
  });

  return deferred.promise;
};

this.cancelServiceFunction = function() {
  return this.canceler.resolve();
};
```

Comment: This is the same answer provided in the link I referenced.  This requires me to change the return object from `myServiceFunction()` which I do not want to do.  It's a pattern that's prevalent throughout my codebase and changing it would require a lot of downstream changes in the controllers

Comment: @LloydBanks It doesn't change the return object from `myServiceFunction()` at all (well, except that this will allow you to use the old `success` and `error` callbacks in your controllers if you wanted to). He just removes the redundant `var deferred = $q.defer();` and adds a canceller token. You can do exactly as you normally would in your controllers without changing a single character.

Comment: I was just trying to clean up your code, which only added overhead. I will update my answer to give you what you want.