# How to cancel a previous request? AngularJS

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs, typescript

I have a grid with a checkbox filter. When I make changes to that filter a request will pe send to server and get data:

```
$http({
    url: this.myUrl,
    params: query
});
```

All good if I make changes at a normal speed, but If I make changes very very fast, lots of requests will be send. In some cases it's possible that last one executes before the last but one.

To avoid getting previous data for last call I want to cancel request if I will do another one.

LIKE:

```
function makeRequest(){
  var request = $http({
        url: this.myUrl,
        params: query
    });

  request.then(({data})=> //do something with data);
}

function program(){
  on('filterChanged') => {
      abortPreviousPendingRequests();  // how to do that? but only for that url!
      makeRequest();
  }
}
```

**========SOLUTION=========**

[get logics from here](https://itnext.io/how-to-cancel-http-requests-in-angularjs-4ccf351319e0)

**you need a global variable:**

```
var promise;

function fetchRequest(query) {
                    const canceller = $q.defer();

                    promise = $http({
                        url: that.yourURL,
                        params: query,
                        timeout: canceller.promise
                    });

                    promise.cancel = () => {
                        canceller.resolve();
                    };
            }
```

before you call fetchRequest(query); you could do this:

```
function cancelPreviousRequest() {
                    if (!promise) {
                        return;
                    }

                    promise.cancel();
                }
```

if you will have promise.then(()=>{}).then(() => {}) etc take a look on that link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cancel an $http request in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928057/how-to-cancel-an-http-request-in-angularjs)

Comment: no, because I want to cancel if request will be executed

Comment: before to make a request I want to cancel previous same requests

Comment: Do you expect the user makes the next request after the successful first request?

Comment: you need to expose var request globally and abort it before execute new

Comment: @ImmanuelKirubaharan yes

Comment: @Jain thanks for your idea, I will try it tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For solution look in question body :)