# JS onclick, override previous click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events

I am writing a query engine where the user enters parameters and then clicks query.
The ng-click event can take up to 7-10 seconds, but rendering of page 1 takes less than a second. If a user wants to re-submit a new query before that time is up there is a bit of a lag because I believe the original function call is still returning.

Is there a way to abruptly stop any previous function calls and only call the most recent?

Below is the query function and the call from the HTML

```
$scope.query = function(name, matchMode, domain) {
        name = name.trim();
        $scope.pageNumber = 0;
        start = 0
        end = $scope.perPage;
        $http.get(ROOT_API+"query/asset/"+name+"/"+matchMode+"/"+domain).success(
            function(data){
                $scope.results=data;
                $scope.displayResults=$scope.results.slice(start,end);
                $scope.totalResults=data.length;
                $scope.totalPages=Math.floor($scope.totalResults / $scope.perPage);
                setPageValues($scope.displayResults)
            });

        setTimeout(function() {
            $scope.displayResults.concat(setPageValues($scope.results.slice(end,$scope.totalResults)))
        },2000);

    }
```

```
<input ng-model="queryName" placeholder="name">
<input ng-model="matchMode" placeholder="match mode" defaultValue="ANYWHERE">
<input ng-model="domain" placeholder="domain" defaultValue="ANY">
<button ng-click="query(queryName, matchMode, domain)">QUERY</button>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to cancel an $http request in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928057/how-to-cancel-an-http-request-in-angularjs)

Comment: @Taplar, I am not looking to cancel based on a timeout.  I want to cancel based on another click event.

Comment: `timeout` there is not a literal timeout.  Timeout is given a deferred/promise.  It is up to you to choose when to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has gone in multiple threading,
first thread has been assigned to code inside you click function from where it has been started and the second one assigned to `http get request`. so first thread gets executed as it ignores next thread execution.
For that sake in javascript, we have callback functions for handling the async calls.
instead of using `setTimeout function`, record the API call response in callback.

```
    let apicallFun = function(requestObj, Callback){
       console.log("Inside API call");
       return $http.get('/your_URL', requestObj)
      .then(function(response){
         Callback(response);
      })
    }
```

and then inside your click function call this `apicallFun` as:

```
$scope.clickFun = function(requestObj){
    apicallFun(requestObj, function(response){
       //according to your response object write the rest of your code.
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please expand on what you mean by "record the API call response in callback"?

Comment: that would be brilliant

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you could wrap the whole thing in a do..while loop and have some exit variable you can set to true?

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer. If it's intended to be an answer,  please provide example code.